# Express, Passport-Google, React - Maintaining correct session information

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, express-session

I've been pouring over SO for a few days now trying to understand my problem, but haven't had much luck.

Using passport-google in my node/express application, I would like to authenticate a user and successfully redirect to my React app (bootstraped using create-react-app) running on a different port with the proper express session set for that port running React.

This is my flow, the problem, and what I've gathered so far:

1. User clicks `<a href="http://localhost:8000/auth/google">Login with Google</a>` on my React application.
2. Passport redirects and presents the user with a login screen and ultimately sends the user back to `auth/google/callback` on my express application
3. `auth/google/callback` sends its successRedirects to my React app on port 3000.

At this point it seems looks like the express session I want tied to port 3000 is connected to port 8000. To be clear, calling a custom `/session` endpoint on port 8000 which sends back the express session shows me what I want, while calling it from 3000 shows me nothing. I'm guessing this happens because it was on port 8000 where the initially. Based off [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48064535/6106255) I think I may be right.

Also, what really confuses me is that when I am redirected back to my React app on port 3000, I see the `connect.sid` cookie with the correct sessionId I see on port 8000. It feels like it did and didn't work at the same time. Why would the connect.sid be set on port 3000, yet any call to req.session delivers no passport information? When/how does that get set? To my understanding passport sets it in the serialization/deserialization process

Also, in general, is what I'm trying to accomplish feasible/worth the effort? I would have thought I would have an easier time figuring this out but it seems like passport might be a good authentication strategy when you are only working with the server itself and a templating language like ejs or even a framework like Next.js.

Ultimately what I want to do is have the user data retrieved from Google handy so I can use it to make calls against my db. I guess if I have the `connect.sid` as a cookie on the React app I could use that to look up the session information on my MongoStore which looks to have what I need, but would it be better just to have that info registered on the server in my session? Also I'm not sure if it's good practice to make my cookies accessible with the httpOnly flag on express-sessions and parsing the cookie using `document.cookie`. I've also used WebSockets on a past project to send information from a server to a client (to negate this same problem), but am not sure if that's a bandaid to my lack of understanding the passport flow or a viable alternative to a problem passport wasn't built to alleviate.

Here is some of the auth flow in no particular order. Any ideas, comments, suggestions, or corrections would be greatly appreciated!

```
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }))
router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google",
    {
        successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000",
        failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/auth-failed",
    }, (req, res) => {
        // empty
    })
)
```

---

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.APP_SECRET || "keyboardcat",
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: dbConnection }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false
    }
  })
)
```

---

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, { _id: user._id })
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findOne(
        { _id: id },
        (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            done(null, user)
        }
    )
})
```

Sidenote: I actually got this working using Next.js because it eliminated the problem of dealing with different ports. If I continue to find it as a viable solution, I could be persuaded to ditch my create-react-app.